# How to add a custom component to createMaterialTopTabNavigator tab bar

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am using `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` from `react-navigation` and trying to customize the tab bar by adding some components on top of it.

As you can see in its guide here:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-top-tab-navigator.html#docsNav

there is an option called `tabBarComponent` that can be passed to create your own tab bar. However, it completely overrides the tab bar which is not what I want.

I'd like to add a custom component at the top of the tab bar and then have the default tabs with their labels underneath.

Can anyone show me an example of how to add a component to the tab bar please?

For example the code bellow replaces the tabs with `My Custom Component` text but how can I have both of them? (custom components and tabs)

```
const myNavigation = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  firstTab: FirstTabScreen,
  secondTab: SecondTabScreen,
  thirdTab: ThirdTabScreen,
},
{
  tabBarComponent: props => (
    <View><Text>My Custom Component</Text></View>
  )
});
```

Comment: In this case you will need to create a custom tab bar component. But it is in fact a lot easier than it sounds, so no worries

Comment: @dentemm that's my problem! I've been trying to create a custom tab bar. And I can assign it to the tabBarComponent. but it removes the original tabs. Do you mind showing me an example please? I've been struggling with it in the past few days, but no luck

Comment: I will show an example of a tab bar I have created!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not so difficult to create a custom tab bar component, below is a mimimised example of a custom tab bar I created for a project I am working on.

But in fact there is not so much to it, your tab bar component receives a navigation prop which holds the different routes you have set up in `createMaterialTopTabNavigator`. So you simply loop over those routes and display an tab bar item for each of them.

**CustomTabBar.jsx**

```
export default class CustomTabBar extends React.Component {

  render() {

    const {navigation} = this.props;    
    const routes = navigation.state.routes;

    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {routes.map((route, index) => {
            return (
              <View style={styles.tabBarItem}>
                <CustomTabBarIcon
                  key={route.key}
                  routeName=route.routeName
                  onPress={() => this.navigationHandler(index)}
                  focused={navigation.state.index === index}
                  index={index}
                />
          </View>
            );
          }
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }

  navigationHandler = (routeName) => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate(routeName);
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignContent: 'center',
    height: 56,
    width: '100%',
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
  tabBarItem: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
});
```

**CustomTabBarItem.jsx**

```
class CustomTabBarIcon extends React.PureComponent {

  render() {

    const {index, focused, routeName} = this.props;
    let icon = '';

    switch (index) {
      case 0: 
        icon = 'a';
        break;

      case 1:
        icon : 'b';
        break;

      case 2:
        icon = 'c';
        break;

      default: 
        iconName = 'a';
    }

    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        onPress={() => this.onSelect(routeName)}
      >
        <View style={[styles.container, focused ? styles.active : styles.inactive]}> 
          <View style={styles.icon}>
            <Icon name={icon} color='white' size={24}/>
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{routeName}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }

  onSelect = (routeName) => {    
    this.props.onPress(routeName);
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  active: {
    borderTopWidth: 3,
    borderColor: 'white'
  },
  inactive: {
    borderTopWidth: 3,
    borderColor: 'blue'  
  },
  textStyle: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 13
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

A very simple approach will be to use Fragment from react. It solves the problem.

```
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';
```

And your component return could look like this

```
return (
        <Fragment>
            <MyCustomHeader/>
            <MaterialTopTabBar/>
        </Fragment>

    )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add your own custom component to the existing top tab bar like this:

```
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator, MaterialTopTabBar } from "react-navigation";

tabBarComponent: props => <SafeAreaView>
  <MyCustomHeader title='test' />
  <MaterialTopTabBar {...props} />
</SafeAreaView>
```