# how to implement a custom tabBarComponent in react native

Tags: react-native

I have a createMaterialToPTabNavigator with 3 tabs / screens I want to customize my tab so I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54409280/how-to-add-a-custom-component-to-creatematerialtoptabnavigator-tab-bar)

I have tried to implement that solution but It didn't work with me :

first issue is that its not showing all my tabs , it shows only one .
secondly - when I press on the label of the tab its displaying an error saying :

> this.props.onPress is not a function

I try to have my 3 tabs on the tab navigator and theirs icons could you please help , this is my code :
 from my routes :

```
const TabBarNavig = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
   Places  : {
   screen :tab1,
   navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: 'Placements'
  }
  )
   },
   GetPlaces : tab2,
   New : tab3
},
{
  tabBarComponent: props => (
    <CustomTabBar {...props} />
  ),
  tabBarPosition: 'top',
swipeEnabled: true,
backBehavior: 'none',
lazy: true,
},
{
  tabBarOptions: {
    scrollEnabled: true,
    labelStyle: {
      fontSize: 10,
      paddingTop:10,
    },
    tabStyle: {
      width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 3,
    }
  }
```

and

export default class CustomTabBar extends Component {

```
render() {

  const {navigation} = this.props;    
  const routes = navigation.state.routes;

  return (

      <View>
        {routes.map((route, index) => {
          return (
            <View>
              <CustomTabBarIcon
                key={route.key}
                routeName={route.routeName}
                onPress={() => this.navigationHandler(index)}
                focused={navigation.state.index === index}
                index={index}
              />
           </View>
          );
        }
        )};
      </View>

  );
}

navigationHandler = (routeName) => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate(routeName);
}
```

}

===========

```
 export default class CustomTabBarIcon extends Component {

    render() {

      const {index, focused, routeName} = this.props;
      let icon = '';

      switch (index) {
        case 0: 
          icon = 'info';
          break;

        case 1:
          icon = 'home';
          break;

        case 2:
          icon = 'account';
          break;

        default: 
          icon = 'info';
      }

      return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
          onPress={this.onSelect}
        >
          <View> 
            <View>
              <Icon name={icon} color='red' size={24}/>
            </View>
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{routeName}</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      );
    }

    onSelect = () => {    
  this.props.onPress(this.props.index);

    }
  }
```

[my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1wte.png)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the answer to the question you are referring to, and I noticed there is a mistake in the code I have provided in the other answer. I fixed that, but there is also something wrong in how you set up the tab bar in `createMaterialTopTabNavigator`. You are providing 3 arguments to the function, but it accepts only 2. The tabBarOptions object should be part of the config object. Also: keep in mind that those options are useless if they are overwritten in your CustomTabBar.

```
const TabBarNavig = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  Places: {
    screen :tab1,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Placements'
    })
  },
  GetPlaces : tab2,
  New : tab3
  },
  {
    tabBarComponent: CustomTabBar,
    tabBarPosition: 'top',
    swipeEnabled: true,
    backBehavior: 'none',
    lazy: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
      scrollEnabled: true,
      labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 10,
        paddingTop:10,
      },
      tabStyle: {
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 3,
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: thanks for responding me , I Have removed one screen but it did not solve my issues , I am on android

Comment: No you shouldn't remove a screen, there was a problem with your configuration. There wasn't anything wrong with the screen setup

Comment: I copied your recent code , and removed some styling from customBarIcon and CustomTabBar , where may it be the problem